# Переопределение php функции

Tags: php

Как переопределить в php функцию `file_get_contents`, таким образом, что если он где-то у меня в скрипте будет вызываться, то в логи выводить те параметры которые ему передаются?

Answer (score 1):

Эта идея от Лукавого =) заходите под ssh на сервер в папку, где сайт лежит и вводите команду:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -H "file_get_contents" {} \;
```

Ниже получите сразу выдачу всех файлов, где она вызывается с цитатами. Так же можете поискать по параметру `eval` .

Или проверьте антивирусом сайт https://www.revisium.com/ai/ - это бесплатно.

Мне кажется, что так правильней.

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php -- она делает то, что вам нужно. Однако для этого должна быть возможность поставить расширение.

Если вы хотите таким образом искать вирус на сайте, то есть более простые методы.

Comment: какие методы ?))

Comment: Выше описали.
Также я вам в вашем вопросе про вирусы рекомендовал утилиту от Яндекса.

Особняком стоит полная выкачка проекта к себе, с включенным антивирусом. Тот же НОД вылавливает скриптовые вирусы своим анализатором.